# Applying SVG Mask over shape Fill

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I want to darken the fill of objects according to the defined gradient below.  However, when the mask goes over the fill, it lightens it instead.  I am assuming this has to be based on the decision on how to blend the colors.  Its using additive colors rather than subtractive.  Do I need to apply a filter on top of the mask?  I feel like there should be an attribute in either the gradient or mask definitions to make it blend the colors the way I want.  Code and fiddle link below:

```
<svg width="400px" height="500px">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="mygradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                    x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
      <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="white"/>                
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="black"/>
    </linearGradient>

      <mask id="mask1" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="500" MaskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation="sRGB">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="500"
        style="stroke:none; fill: url(#mygradient)"/>
  </mask>
  </defs>



  <g fill="red" mask= "url(#mask1)" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"
    feblend="Multiply">

    <rect x="5" y="5" width="390" height="90"/>
    <rect x="5" y="105" width="390" height="90"/>
    <rect x="5" y="205" width="390" height="90"/>
    <rect x="5" y="305" width="390" height="90"/>
     <rect x="5" y="405" width="390" height="90"/>

  </g>

</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6q3x8x5u/

Comment: Not sure, but is this what you are looking for ? [**filddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nezw5oh7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the mask with a simple `<rect>` with the proper blend mode.

(Below the `<g>`):

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="500" style="stroke:none;
  fill: url(#mygradient); mix-blend-mode: multiply" />
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6q3x8x5u/1/)

Comment: Thats close.  Can something be added so that it doesnt mix the white that is the gap between each red rect? I just want the red mixed.  This is because the widths will not be constant also so I just want the mask overly to apply to what will be displayed

Comment: @tormond Unfortunately no (if using this method), since it blends a simple rect on top of whatever is below without "understanding" what's there. Pauls's answer fixes this artifact but depends on the fill attribute so if you need that to something else (an image for example) you'll have a harder time.

Answer (score 0):

Why the mask?  Masks are used to vary the transparency, not the colour.

You have a gradient in your SVG that you are not using.  If you adjust the colours of the gradient, you can get what it sounds like you want.

```html
<svg width="400px" height="500px">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="mygradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                    x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
      <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="red"/>                
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="black"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
  
  
  <g fill="url(#mygradient)" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"
    feblend="Multiply">

    <rect x="5" y="5" width="390" height="90"/>
    <rect x="5" y="105" width="390" height="90"/>
    <rect x="5" y="205" width="390" height="90"/>
    <rect x="5" y="305" width="390" height="90"/>
     <rect x="5" y="405" width="390" height="90"/>

  </g>

</svg>
```